# how to set radiogroup radiofield based on the json data extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

hi forum member I am having one problem with setting the radiofield in the extjs 4

**my form radiogroup xtype code is given below**

```
{
  xtype: 'radiogroup',
  dataIndex: 'gender',
  margin: 5,
  fieldLabel: 'Gender',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'radiofield',
    name: 'gender',
    boxLabel: 'Male',
    inputValue:'0'
  }, {
    xtype: 'radiofield',
    name: 'gender',
    boxLabel: 'Female',
    inputValue:'1'
  }]
}
```

**my json data I am receiving is**

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "success": true,
  "employeedata": [{
     "username": "yaryan997",
     "surname": "Singh",        
     "firstname": "Yogendra",
     "gender": false
  }]
}
```

**my employee list view has action column editEmployee which executes the below function**

```
editEmployee:function(grid,no,rowindex,colindex,temp) {
        alert('Edit EMPLOYEE button pressed');
        var rec = grid.store.getAt(rowindex);
        var employeeid = rec.get('id');

        store = grid.getStore();
        store.load({
            params: {'employeeid':employeeid},
            scope: this,
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                //the operation object contains all of the details of the load operation
                console.log(records);
                this.getEmployeeEdit().editform=1;
                this.getEmployeeEditForm().loadRecord(rec);                 
                this.getEmployeeEdit().show();
            }
        });
        this.getEmployeeStore().load();
    },
```

based on the id the editEmployee view is shown. My edit Employee shows all the values correctly but only the problem is with the radiofield. They didn't show the selected value.

**my json data I had provide you which comes as employeedata**

I am not able to set the radiogroup gender based on the data i am receiving from the json.

please suggest me some solution for it.

Comment: Your radios inputValues are strings, and the data type of 'gender' on your json is bool. Maybe an issue there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should set `inputValue` to 'false' and 'true'. The second is the new design of a radiogroup. You will find the solution in my thread at the sencha forum See: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?187185-Set-a-int-value-on-a-radiogroup-fails&goto=newpost

The problem is that `setValue` is expecting a object which would only be the case if you had to datatypes for gender; one for male and one for female... And that's the point why I posted this as bug. Down the override code from my post.

```
setValue: function (value) {
    if (!Ext.isObject(value)) {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj[this.name] = value;
        value = obj;
    }
    Ext.form.RadioGroup.prototype.setValue.call(this, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that you are trying to pass a boolean value to your `radioBox`:

```
"gender": false
```

which you are not supposed to.

The `radioBox` will be set to checked/unchecked if a `true`/`false` value is passed to its `setValue` method, ignoring what is the `inputValue` field set to.

Here is the source code, we can see that any other value passed in will finally end with a recursive call with boolean parameter:

```
setValue: function(v) {
    var me = this,
        active;

    if (Ext.isBoolean(v)) {
        me.callParent(arguments);
    } else {
        active = me.getManager().getWithValue(me.name, v, me.getFormId()).getAt(0);
        if (active) {
            active.setValue(true);
        }
    }
    return me;
}
```