# Load radio button/combo box data from JSON data

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to auto select radio button and combo box values of a form using JSON data. But, everything else (text boxes/ check boxes / data fields) is getting populated. I had no success auto selecting a value of the radio group or the combo box.

**As suggested by Satya, here is the link to the jsfiddle. Clicking a row on the "movie database" populates the data in the "movie information form".**

> http://jsfiddle.net/9PVCN/5/

Thanks a lot in advance for help.

Here is the part of my form -

```
              { 
                xtype:'radiogroup',
                columns:1,
                fieldLabel:'Filmed In',
                name: 'filmed_in',
                items:[{
                    name:'filmed_in',
                    boxLabel: 'Color',
                    inputValue: 'color'
                },{
                    name:'filmed_in',
                    boxLabel: 'B&W',
                    inputValue: 'B&W'
                }                   
                ]

            },{             
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Bad Movie',
                    name: 'bad_movie',
                    checked: true
              },{
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    hiddenName: 'genre',
                    fieldLabel: 'Genre',
                    mode: 'local',
                    store: genres,
                    displayField:'url',
                    valueField:'name',
                    width: 250,
                    editable: false,
                    listeners: {select: comboSelect}
              },
```

This is how the **genres** store is coded -

```
var genres = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        storeId: 'genres',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'genres.data',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: 'name'
            }
        },
        fields: ['name', 'url']
    });
```

The url **genres.data** returns this -

```
[{"name":"1","url":"Comedy"},{"name":"2","url":"Drama"},{"name":"3","url":"Action"}]
```

This is the data I am trying to load into the form -

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "title":"Office Space",
  "director":"Mike Judge",
  "released":"02/27/1999",
  "genre":"1",
  "bad_movie": "1",
  "filmed_in": "color",
  "description": "Loved watching this ....."
```

}

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle please , that way it will help us to look at all of code @ once

Comment: Converting the `filmed_in` value can do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/9PVCN/7/

Comment: Thanks CD. Any ideas on why combo box is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the radio button the expected value is different then your passing.

Instead of `filmed_in: 'color'` you'll need to pass `filmed_in: { filmed_in: 'color' }`.

You can override the `setValue` as [sra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953313/139300) mentioned so it will work with `filmed_in: 'color'`:

```
setValue: function (value) {
    if (!Ext.isObject(value)) {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj[this.name] = value;
        value = obj;
    }
    Ext.form.RadioGroup.prototype.setValue.call(this, value);
}
```

For the combobox, just add  `name: 'genre'`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PVCN/9/